# php error when retrieving multiple rows from server

Tags: php, mysql

i m trying to get a json for my android application but i m getting an error:
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in **/home/a5872453/public_html/GetAllGreenhouse.php** on line **17**

this is my code:

```
  <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql3.000webhost.com","xxx","xxx","xxx");

$farmname = $_POST["farmname"];


 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM GreenHouse WHERE farm_name = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $farmname);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $ghid, $name, $farmname, $planttype, $linefrom, $lineto, $barcode);



$response["greenhouses"] = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement)){
        $greenhouse= array();
    $greenhouse["ghid"]=$row[$ghid];
    $greenhouse["name"]=$row[$name];
    $greenhouse["farmname"]=$row[$farmname];
    $greenhouse["planttype"]=$row[$planttype];
        $greenhouse["linefrom"]=$row[$linefrom];
        $greenhouse["lineto"]=$row[$lineto];
        $greenhouse["barcode"]=$row[$barcode];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["greenhouses"], $greenhouse);
}


echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Your query failed and you need to find out why. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Plus, you tagged as "android" which I removed. No relevant code to support the question. If so, add your Android code (if relevant) then add the tag back in.

Comment: what does adding `var_dump($row)` inside the while loop give you? You might also want to take a look at the syntax here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php. I think using that your code can be further simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...Thanks i  solved it. here is the correct code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("mysql3.000webhost.com","xxx","xxx","xxx");
$farmname = $_POST["farmname"];


 $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM GreenHouse WHERE farm_name= ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $farmname);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $ghid, $name, $farmname, $planttype, $linefrom, $lineto,$barcode);

$greenhouses["greenhouses"] = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
     $greenhouse= array();
    $greenhouse["ghid"]=$ghid;
    $greenhouse["name"]=$name;
    $greenhouse["farmname"]=$farmname;
    $greenhouse["planttype"]=$planttype;
        $greenhouse["linefrom"]=$linefrom;
        $greenhouse["lineto"]=$lineto;
        $greenhouse["barcode"]=$barcode;
   array_push($greenhouses["greenhouses"], $greenhouse);

}

echo json_encode($greenhouses);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```